# DataGridButtonColumn

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I want to create a `DataGridColumn` with a `Button` in it. Seems easy enough right?

Only:

- Customer should be able to navigate the grid columns using arrows.
- When `DataGridGolumn` with a `Button` in it has the focus, an enter should activate the command. (eg not needing to press tab to get focus on the button)
- Use <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> to click the button

I've tried a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `CellTemplate`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Button}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource LinkButton}" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="Delete" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Image Source="Delete.ico"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to focus your button as soon as Cell gets in focus, you should set `KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop` to `False` on DataGridCell -

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Button}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        ....
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

So, when you press `Tab`, it will find that `DataGridCell` is not the stop point here so move to next tab stop which will be your `Button`.

You can create the `Style` in resources and use it wherever you want the same behaviour.

Comment: When using arrows the focus is still on the datagridcell. Only when pressing Tab the button gets the focus (which is better then two tabs.. but still)